# In iOS how we come back to initial view after google+ sharing?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-plus

I am implementing google plus sharing successfully by using the following lines of code. But after sharing it doesn't come back to initial screen. Is there any delegate call after completing the procedure of sharing

```
- (void)googelSharing{

    //Set bool for Handler 
    [self setUserDefaultForSharing:NO];

    GPPSignIn  *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.clientID = kClientId;

    signIn.scopes = @[@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"];

    id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog];

    // This line will fill out the title, description, and thumbnail from
    // the URL that you are sharing and includes a link to that URL.
    [shareBuilder setURLToShare:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com/restaurant/sf/1234567/"]];

    [shareBuilder open];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google + iPhone API sign in and share without leaving app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281386/google-iphone-api-sign-in-and-share-without-leaving-app)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because when u request to open the specific web page iOS automatically transfer this request to Safari .  And Safari  will open that web page.

One thing you can do is used [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/) in your app and open the web page inside `UIWebView` and u can easily get back to pervious  `viewController` OR web page  by adding simple `UIButton` in `currentViewController` class.

Here is code

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
NSString *urlString = @"https://www.example.com/restaurant/sf/1234567/";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

If u are used `UIWebView` than refer this answer it will help you [Back Button on UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704950/back-button-on-uiwebview)

Comment: This does not really answer the question.

Comment: @ JAL  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281386/google-iphone-api-sign-in-and-share-without-leaving-app answer is wright. But that answer is applicable  without opening the web page inside your application. if you want to open web page, using the UIWebView inside the app is good choice

Answer (score 0):

For your information Apple will reject the app if you use

*a web page in mobile Safari for creating an account or logging in, then returns the user to the app.*

See this [discussion](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/37).

So Google release new **Google Plus SDK** for sign in

Google Sign In SDK 2.0 is documented on the new dev site :

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/

Hope this helps